# This Arthmetic Operation in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with almost same structure as seen below with some datas,

`table name = myshop structure (id_no, time, teams, home, draw, away)`

`table name = myshop2 structure (id_no, time, teams, home, draw, away)`

`table name = myshop3 structure (id_no, teams, home, draw, away)`

```
 `TABLE NAME: MYSHOP
  ID_NO TIME    TEAMS                          HOME DRAW    AWAY
  209   00:00   FK PARTIZAN vs CSKA MOSCOW  3.3 3.75    1.85
  210   00:00   RAPID VIENNA vs CELTIC          2.6 3.3 2.3
  211   00:00   SPARTAK MOSCOW vs FK VOZDOVAC   1.3 5.2 6.75
  212   00:00   LUDOGORETS vs DINAMO MOSCOW 2.2 3.35    2.6
  213   00:00   FC THUN vs FC ZURICH            1.9 3.8 2.6
  214   01:00   FC NURNBERG vs BOHEMIANS 1905   1.45    3.9 4.6
  215   01:00   LILLESTROM vs STROMSGODSET  1.0 3.5 3.35
  216   01:00   HALMSTAD vs IF ELFSBORG         2.4 3.5 2.0
  217   05:00   FLANDRIA vs CHACARITA JUNIORS   3.78    2.67    2.54
  218   05:00   CA RIVER PLATE vs DANUBIO   3.25    3.15    2.7
  219   05:00   JUVENTUD vs CERRO           3.55    3.15    2.3

  TABLE NAME: MYSHOP 2
  ID_NO TIME    TEAMS                          HOME DRAW    AWAY
  9     00:00   FK PARTIZAN vs CSKA MOSCOW      2.3 3.75    1.85
  10    00:00   RAPID VIENNA vs CELTIC          1.6 3.3      2.3
  11    00:00   SPARTAK MOSCOW vs FK VOZDOVAC   2.3 5.2      6.75
  12    00:00   LUDOGORETS vs DINAMO MOSCOW     1.2 3.35     2.6
  13    00:00   FC THUN vs FC ZURICH            2.9 3.8      2.6
  14    01:00   FC NURNBERG vs BOHEMIANS 1905   2.453.9      4.6
  15    01:00   LILLESTROM vs STROMSGODSET      1.0 3.5      3.35
  16    01:00   HALMSTAD vs IF ELFSBORG         2.4 3.5      2.0
  17    05:00   FLANDRIA vs CHACARITA JUNIORS   1.782.67     2.54
  18    05:00   CA RIVER PLATE vs DANUBIO   1.25    3.15    2.7
  19    05:00   JUVENTUD vs CERRO           1.55    3.15    2.3


  TABLE NAME: MYSHOP 3
  ID_NO TEAMS                          HOME DRAW    AWAY
  33    FK PARTIZAN vs CSKA MOSCOW     2.3  2.75    2.85
  10    RAPID VIENNA vs CELTIC          1.6 2.3 2.3
  11    SPARTAK MOSCOW vs FK VOZDOVAC   2.3 3.2 6.75
  21    LUDOGORETS vs DINAMO MOSCOW     1.2 2.35    2.6
  31    FC THUN vs FC ZURICH            2.9 2.8 2.6
  42    FC NURNBERG vs BOHEMIANS 1905   2.45    2.9 4.6
  53    LILLESTROM vs STROMSGODSET       3.0    2.5 3.35
  64    HALMSTAD vs IF ELFSBORG         2.4 2.5 2.0
  75    FLANDRIA vs CHACARITA JUNIORS   1.78    1.67    2.54
  86    CA RIVER PLATE vs DANUBIO       1.25    1.15    2.7
  97    JUVENTUD vs CERRO               1.55    1.15    2.3
```

`

Is it possible to perform a single arthmetic op

Datas that exist in those table have same teams values but different values on `HOME`, `DRAW` & `AWAY` so what i want is a sql syntax that will perform this specification.

It should take value of `home` in `myshop` table divide by 1, value of `draw` in `myshop2` table divide by 1, value of `away` in `myshop3` table divide by 1 then sum all the values and get one value for each team, and the output should be total with the corresponding team like simple example below.

`FK PARTIZAN vs CSKA MOSCOW 105`

IDEALLY SYNTAX IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE

`SELECT from MYSHOP(home/1)+MYSHOP2(draw/1)+MYSHOP3(away/1) where TEAMS(MYSHOP=MYSHOP2=MYSHOP3)`

Need your thoughts guys on this.

Comment: Also, dividing by 1 do nothing you know...

Comment: You are just missing some `JOIN`, it should be `(MYSHOP.home/1)+(MYSHOP2.draw/1)+...` and the arithmetic should be in the `SELECT` not the `FROM` and i skip some other obvious mistakes. I think you should read (or re-read) a SQL tutorial they usually have exemples to do just that. They are called calculated columns.

Comment: But is it really possible to be executed if i re-read? worry out about dividing by 1. @litelite

Comment: How did you get 105 from the numbers 3.3, 3.75, 1.85, 2.3, 3.75, 1.85, 2.3, 2.75, 2.85?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your syntax wish and syntax reality are not matched.

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve but relying strings such as `SPARTAK MOSCOW vs FK VOZDOVAC` to join is not likely to work well. For example should these "join":

1. SPARTAK MOSCOW vs FK VOZDOVAC
2. FK VOZDOVAC vs SPARTAK MOSCOW

Consider this as a way to combine those 3 tables:

```
      SELECT
            1 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            2 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            3 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop3
```

The try this:

```
SELECT
      teams
    , SUM(home)
    , SUM(draw)
    , SUM(away)
FROM (
      SELECT
            1 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            2 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            3 tbl_src, id_no, teams, home, draw, away
      FROM myshop3
) AS d
GROUP BY
      teams
```